# How to set a default year datepicker react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react datepicker, I would like to set a default year(1990) when the calender is open, tried 'date', 'initialDate' prop  but it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
const defaultYear = new Date("1990-01-01")

<LentoFormikDatePicker
      name='date_of_birth'
      label='Date of birth'
      value={values.date_of_birth}
      setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
      maxDate={addYearsToDate(-18)}
      minDate={addYearsToDate(-100)}
      date={defaultYear}
  />
```

Comment: What is LentoFormikDatePicker? A library or your own component?

Comment: If you use [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker), there is property 'selected'.

Comment: @BK52 I tried the property selected but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-date-picker and the sample working code for the functionality you asked is given below:

Sample Code

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

function App() {
  // const defaultYear = new Date("1990-01-01")
  const [defaultYear, setdefaultYear] = useState(new Date("1990-01-01"));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <DatePicker
         selected={defaultYear}
         name='date_of_birth'
         label='Date of birth'
         onChange={(date) => setdefaultYear(date)}
         // value={values.date_of_birth}
         // setFieldValue={setdefaultYear}
         // maxDate={addYearsToDate(-18)}
         // minDate={addYearsToDate(-100)}
         //date={defaultYear}
       />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The below urls will help in getting more details about react date-picker.

https://kandi.openweaver.com/javascript/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker